# using Linux vncviewer

Tags: remote-desktop, remote

when i am connecting to VNC server using wine on linux

> $ wine vncviewer.exe

i have to enter:

> VNC Server: 1.1.1.21
>
> Proxy/Reapeter: 195.29.18.33:1234

and then, when i connect, on top there is txt:
1.1.1.21:5900 (195.29.18.33:1234)

mine question is: how to connect using vncviewer ?

what to put in VNC_VIA_CMD ?

> $ export xlocalPort=1234
>
> $ export xremoteHost=1.1.1.21
>
> $ export xremotePort=5900
>
> $ export xgateway=195.29.18.33
>
> $ export VNC_VIA_CMD="/usr/bin/ssh -f -L $xlocalPort:$xremoteHost:$xremotePort $xgateway sleep 20"
>
> $ vncviewer $xremoteHost -via $xgateway

and i get error:

> unable connect to socket: Connection refused (111)

i was trying to help myself with page

http://www.tightvnc.com/vncviewer.1.php

Please help, couse i need to use "native" linux vncviewer installed by

> $ yum install tigervnc
>
> tigervnc.i686 0:1.0.90-0.13.20100420svn4030.fc13

Thnx

Comment: What *exactly* is your question?  e.g., "How do you connect via a proxy using tightvnc...?"

Comment: yes Redmumba, how do you connect via a proxy using tightvnc from linux.

when i am working with wine and win version of vncviewer, than it works fine...

maybe i just mix server names and ports in VNC_VIA_CMD ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
$ vncviewer -via $xgateway $xremoteHost
```

...instead? Order matters in Linux.